# How do I construct The Horizon postgresql string to connect to a unix socket

Tags: horizon

I've successfully gotten stellar-core itself to connect to my postgresql database using a Unix socket, like this:
`DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellarb user=stellarb host=/var/run/postgresql"`
Now, I want Horizon to connect over the socket as well, but horizon keeps saying that the database at /var/run/postgresql/horizon can't be found. Here is my connection string:
`--db-url postgresql://horizon@/var/run/postgresql/horizon`

How would I modify this connection to point to the socket successfully? Does Horizon support connecting over Unix sockets? I'm performing a stress test and think connecting over sockets will speed up the response time of Horizon somewhat. Right now I'm connecting over localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horizon is using [`github.com/lib/pq`](https://github.com/lib/pq) Golang package to connect to Postgres. This package is using a different connection string. From the [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Connection_String_Parameters):

> host - The host to connect to. Values that start with / are for unix
>     domain sockets. (default is localhost)

So for you, the connection string should look like:

```
user=horizon host=/var/run/postgresql/horizon
```

---

Please note that when using spaces in CLI command params you may need to enquote them like:

```
--db-url="user=horizon host=/var/run/postgresql/horizon"
```